# C# write settings class application scope on first run

Tags: c#, save, settings, guid, readonly

I want to setup application code for my application, so I made a readonly settings field with GUID for that, how can I set that field to random on my application first run?

I tried like that:

```
internal sealed partial class ApplicationSettings 
{
    public ApplicationSettings() {
    //If installation code not set yet, assign a new one
    if (this.InstallationCode == System.Guid.Empty)
    {
        this["InstallationCode"] = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Save();
    }
...
}
```

But it doesn't save the code, it gives me a random code on every run. How can this be done?

**EDIT** If it can only be written during installation process, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Access to application.exe.config is readonly per definition. One reason is, because this file is protected by UAC when located in the programs directory. So you cannot modify it without administration privileges, even if .NET framework would allow it (which it does not).

1. You could write this value in the installation process (if you have one).
2. Another possibility would be storing the value in the registry. But I think you need admin rights for the HKLM part too.

Comment: How can i write it in installation process?

Comment: Well, that depends on the product you are using. (for instance InstallShield, InnoSetup, WiX, VS-One Click, ...)

Answer (score 1):

You better do that as part of the installation process if you want to have it the app.config file. Second option is to attempt to load the file as a regular XML document and insert the GUID in the document, then save it to file. If the file doesn't have writing permissions then you'll have to find another way, perhaps as UAC in your app.

Something like this will work, though you will probably need to hold that newly created GUID to use in the first application run:

```
    private void CreateNewGUIDIfNotExist()
    {
        string configFilePath = "myAppName.exe.config";
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(configFilePath);

        var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings");

        foreach (XmlNode settingNode in node.SelectNodes("add"))
        {
            if (settingNode.Attributes["key"].Value == "MyGUID")
            {
                var guidNode = settingNode.Attributes["value"];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(guidNode.Value))
                    guidNode.Value = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                doc.Save(configFilePath);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

You will need to start with an empty  GUID like this if you don't want to create the node in the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyGUID" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```